# Intel Pin under Valgrind. Library error?

Tags: valgrind, 32bit-64bit, libc, libc++, intel-pin

When i run intel pin under valgrind i get the following error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-x86-linux.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
```

i have valgrind-3.10.1

with

```
dpkg -l | grep libc6
```

i get

```
ii  libc6:amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.9  amd64  Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6:i386  2.19-0ubuntu6.9  i386  Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-dbg:amd64  2.19-0ubuntu6.9  amd64  Embedded GNU C Library: detached debugging symbols
ii  libc6-dbg:i386  2.19-0ubuntu6.9  i386  Embedded GNU C Library: detached debugging symbols
ii  libc6-dev:amd64  2.19-0ubuntu6.9  amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
ii  libc6-i386  2.19-0ubuntu6.9  amd64  Embedded GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
```

any suggestions?

Comment: This looks somewhat similar to bug https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=286270 vgpreload is not friendly to 64->32 bit execs, gives ld.so warnings. But this bug was fixed before 3.10. You might run with -v -v -v -d -d -d to have more traces about what valgrind is doing with the LD_PRELOAD

Comment: I'm wondering why you tagged this with libc++